# Clickhouse doesn't show new size after EBS volume resizing

Tags: clickhouse

We have Clickhouse running on EC2 with EBS volume attached. We successfully increased disk size using AWS guide which works flawless.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

But using Clikhouse
`SELECT * FROM system.disks;` We do see the old size of disk.

We also stopped and started server again. In config.xml I couldn't find and disk space related configuration.

Comment: Did you  execute `sudo xfs_growfs -d /`  - Extend the file system?  Do you see the new size in `df -h` ?

Comment: Indeed you're right! We misinterpreted the guide and missed the last step. Then all worked out fine and CH immediately showed the new disk space!